# Jantar dos Filósofos em Python

Tags: python, algoritmo

Gostaria de saber se alguém já implementou o algorítimo do Jantar dos filósofos em python.

Estou precisando fazer ele, porém só acho exemplos com implementação usando thread e preciso fazer sem usar thread.

Comment: Se você nos mostrar o que já implementou, poderemos lhe ajudar.

Comment: Se você não pode usar thread, você pode usar o que então? Processos?

Comment: Exatamente. Preciso fazer comunicação entre processos e tratar os casos de deadlock e starvation.

Comment: Sugiro dar uma olhada no pacote [`multiprocessing`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html), ele possui uma API semelhante ao do módulo `threading` (simplificando sua adaptação). A título de exemplo, você pode criar um `Lock` para representar o recurso compartilhado, usando `l.acquire()` e `l.release()` para pegá-lo e soltá-lo, respectivamente. [Aqui tem um exemplo](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#synchronization-between-processes). E qual a necessidade de comunicação pra esse algoritmo? Que eu saiba, os filósofos não interagem diretamente entre eles...

Comment: Se este é um problema "amplo" não sei o o que seria específico. Uma pergunta não precisa ser um tratado.